# ASP.NET looking for a way to pad a string with 0 or blanks

Tags: asp.net

Hey im looking for a way to do the following to populate a text file

if I need to fill a alphanumeric column with Field size 20 and I only have 18 characters to append two blank values.

then same for numeric values if field size is 10 for example and i have a value of 5 characters to fill in remaining spaces with 5 0's

i.e instead of 10000 i would have 0000010000

Comment: Are you asking how to do this in ASp.net (client code) or code-behind in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string s = "10000";
string t = s.PadLeft(20, '0');
```

Comment: Surely there is a way without code-behind? Something like ((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["yourcolumn"].ToString("{0},####") ??

Answer (score 2):

[The `PadLeft` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) should do the trick.  Something like this:

```
var output = myTextString.PadLeft(20);
```

or

```
var output = myNumericString.PadLeft(10, '0');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some pseudocode that should do it:

```
int size = mystring.length();
int padding = 20 - size;
string pad = "";
for(padding){
    pad += "0";
}
string newstring = pad + mystring;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qtzTu/

Answer (score 1):

How to Pad a Number with Leading Zeroes:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048.aspx

Answer (score -1):

The OP implied the string lengths would vary, so here is a Func where you won't have to **hard code values** like "10" or "20"

```
Func<string, int, string> PadStringToSize = (x,y) 
                    => (x.Length < y ? x.PadLeft(y, '0') : x);
```

You can then do things like:

```
Console.WriteLine(PadStringToSize("10000", 10)); // Pads to 10
Console.WriteLine(PadStringToSize("10000", 30)); // Pads to 30
```

Then you can just wrap the call to a method that takes the size as a parameter instead hard coding the desired length.

Comment: How does this differ from just using `PadLeft`?  According to the MSDN docs, `PadLeft` will return a reference to the original string if it's longer than the intended length, or a copy of the original if it equals the intended length.  Your code doesn't seem to be adding any value to that functionality.  Also, note that in your usage example (after your edit) you are hard-coding the intended sizes.  So, again, what's the gain here?

Comment: It "seems" != certainity. Also see the last line => Then you can just wrap the call to a method that takes the size as a parameter instead hard coding the desired length.

Comment: And the code which calls that method would supply it... the desired length.  So, instead of supplying the desired length to `PadLeft`, you're supplying it to a method wrapped around a `Func` wrapped around `PadLeft`.

Comment: So yeah, if he has 15 columns he needs to work with of varying sizes, I'm sure writing a separate line for each column is an ideal solution.